# Promisify a function which returns null

Tags: javascript, node-promisify

This function returns null and I need to promisify it. but I don't understand this code. Can anyone help with this.

```
return iyzipay.payment.create(req, function (err, result) {
    return('result:'+ result + 'error:'+ err);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in a `Promise` and call either `resolve` or `reject` once the operation is completed.

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    iyzipay.payment.create(req, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        } else {
            resolve(result)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you for this correct answer. really thank you!